# Computability - Can a Turing Machine calculate the input's length?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I have looked for an answer for this question which seems trivial, but I didn't find any.

```
Can a Turing machine, given a word w, calculate the length of the word?
```

Comment: Yeah, it can https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370436/turing-machine-that-calculates-words-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, certainly! Here’s something to think about:

- How would you design a TM to increment a binary number?
- How could you use that other TM as a subroutine to count the input length?

Another perspective: remember that by the Church-Turing thesis anything you can do with any effective model of computation you can do with a TM, so since other models can measure input length, TMs can do it as well.